# How to get the output of the built-in help() function in python in a string?

Tags: python

As a example :

```
>>> out = help(list) ## out must be a string .
>>> print out 
>>> ' Help on class list in module __builtin__:

class list(object)
 |  list() -> new empty list
 |  list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items '
```

Any advice highly appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the **doc**

```
print list.__doc__
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import pydoc
pydoc.render_doc(list)
```

gives the whole output of `help(list)`. If you're just interested in the top description (and not all methods defined on the object), use

```
list.__doc__
```